# Maximum number of collinear points - optimization

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, coordinate-systems

I stumbled across this problem :

> "A tourist have a map of dimensions M x N. On the map are plased k
>   cities (k<=2000). Cities' coordinates have that form (lin, col)
>   (lin<=M and col<=N). We know the tourist's coordinates as well. The
>   tourist decided to take in a certain direction and to stop at the edge
>   of the map. But he wants to walk on the direction that makes him walk
>   through as many cities as posible. You have to calculate the maximum
>   number of cities that he can visit."
>
> M, N <= 1000
>
> K<=2000
>
> e.g.   5 10 (M and N)
>
> 3 2 (tourist's coordinates)
>
> 7 (k = number of cities)
>
> 0 0 (coordinates of the cities)
>
> 0 8
>
> 1 6
>
> 2 2
>
> 2 4
>
> 3 7
>
> 4 5
>
> Answer : 3

[image]
Actually, the problem requires the maximum number of collinear points that includes the tourist coordonates.

I've found a solution that is O(k^2).

```
for(i=0; i<k; i++) {
    fscanf(fi, "%d%d", &lin[i], &col[i]);
    lin[i]-=l; //we consider tourist's coordinates the origin
    col[i]-=c;
}
for(i=0; i<k; i++) {
    points=1;
    for(j=0; j<k; j++) {
         ...
         if(lin[i] * col[j] == lin[j] * col[i]) //verify collinearity
             points++; 
  ...
}
```

But I'm pretty sure that it can be done better than O(k^2). I didn't find any optimizations yet.

Comment: Are you sure that this problem is equivalent to finding the maximum number of collinear points which includes the traveler's coordinates? Because if he walks in a straight line away from his starting position, he can't visit points that are behind him (on the other side of his starting position), even if they are on the same line as his starting position and the points he is walking towards.

Comment: Direction (as in what Adrian said) can be determined via a simple boolean. All the points to the right of the traveler's position (on the x axis) get a value of true, the ones to the left get a false. This way you have (slope,direction) as a key.

Comment: The only case where this is not enough is when a point is on the same vertical axis with the traveler's position. In this case you set direction to true if the point is more to the North and to false if it is more to the South than the traveler's position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compute the slope of the line determined by the coordinates of the traveller and each point. You now have an array of slopes. You can now order this array and see which is the one slope that appears the most times. Or you can hash the slopes (to avoid sorting the array).

Comment: @scummy You can by example take an array of 1000 booleans (that should be ok in your case) and take the most significant 3 digits of your slopes as keys in your improvised hash table, mark the corresponding position in you hash table and each time you run into a slope that has has the same key you assume it is the same slope.

Comment: A hash is key to this.  Without one, you're stuck sorting k's by slope, O(nlogn).

Comment: @scummy: yes-- but you owe it to yourself to get familiar with hashes.  They are absolutely essential knowledge.

Comment: @scummy No problem. The improvised hash approach in this particular case might just pass all test cases since your map is not that big.

Comment: @scummy Also, pay attention to the fact that in this case the slope is not exactly enough, you also need direction since a point on the same line might be in the opposite direction the traveler walks.

Comment: also, make sure to account for the fact that the traveler might walk straight up or down, in which case the slope doesn't exist

Comment: @scummy In the case Adrian is talking about you can just set the value of the slope to MAX_DOUBLE (that is a value the slope cannot get on your particular case, because the map is to small for that)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in O(n).  With tourist's coordinates defined as the origin, two cities k1 and k2 are colinear if the lines (t,k1) and (t,k2) have the same slope.  If you store your k values in a hash by slope, this only requires one pass through all k and then one pass through the slopes computed to find the slope with the most ks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to implement it, just to get familliar with hash tables